# c++ boost socket proxy-server add SSL

Tags: c++, sockets, boost

I'm using http proxy-sever with boost libs. Like: 
WebBrowser  <-> Socket-ProxyServer <-> http Server. It's work fine. But I have a SSL-certificate and it's need to add then to my Proxy-server.  My code is:

proxy-server.cpp:

```
    server::server(const ios_deque& io_services, int port, std::string interface_address, int num)
    : io_services_(io_services),
      endpoint_(interface_address.empty()?  
                (ba::ip::tcp::endpoint(ba::ip::tcp::v4(), port)): 
                ba::ip::tcp::endpoint(ba::ip::address().from_string(interface_address), port) ),    
      acceptor_(*io_services.front(), endpoint_)    
{
    start_accept(num);
}

void server::start_accept(int num) {
    io_services_.push_back(io_services_.front());
    io_services_.pop_front();
    connection::pointer new_connection = connection::create(*io_services_.front());
        acceptor_.async_accept(new_connection->socket(),
                           boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_connection,
                                       ba::placeholders::error, num));

        }

void server::handle_accept(connection::pointer new_connection, const bs::error_code& error, int num) {
    if (!error) {
            new_connection->start(GlobalSett.CheckIp(inet_addr(new_connection->socket().remote_endpoint().address().to_string().c_str())), num);

            start_accept(num); 
    }

}
```

proxy-server.hpp:

```
typedef std::deque<io_service_ptr> ios_deque;

class server {
public:
    server(const ios_deque& io_services, int port, std::string interface_address, int);

private:
    void start_accept(int);
    void handle_accept(connection::pointer new_connection, const bs::error_code& error, int);

    ios_deque io_services_;
    const ba::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint_;   
    ba::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_;         
    function FUNC;
};
```

and start server:

```
try {
        int thread_num = atoi(GlobalSett.GetSetConfig("PROXY_THREAD[" + std::to_string(num) + "]")), port = atoi(GlobalSett.GetSetConfig("PROXY_LISTNER_PORT["+std::to_string(num)+"]"));
        std::string interface_address = GlobalSett.GetSetConfig("PROXY_LISTNER_IP["+ std::to_string(num)+"]");

        ios_deque io_services;
        std::deque<ba::io_service::work> io_service_work;

        boost::thread_group thr_grp;

        for (int i = 0; i < thread_num; ++i) {
            io_service_ptr ios(new ba::io_service);
            io_services.push_back(ios);
            io_service_work.push_back(ba::io_service::work(*ios));
            thr_grp.create_thread(boost::bind(&ba::io_service::run, ios));
        }
        server server(io_services, port, interface_address, num);
        thr_grp.join_all();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
```

It's need to add ssl to server socket. Any one can help with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [boost::asio::ssl:stream](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream.html). Have a look at boost asio SSL examples: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/ssl/server.cpp

If you need SSL functionality not exposed in boost::asio::ssl::stream you can always use [native_handle()](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream/native_handle.html):

```
boost::asio::ssl::stream<asio:ip::tcp::socket> sock(io_context, ctx);
...
SSL_use_certificate(sock.native_handle(), x509_certificate);
...
```

Comment: Please read the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can help you with specific questions, but not write your code. It's also nice to upvote answers if you found them useful.